How are we to understand future prophecy fulfillment concerning extinct nations?
In Isaiah , the prophecy about the root of Jesse, there is reference to the people of Moab,Ammon and edom and of nations like Shinar (Babylon) which have already passed away. There are other such prophecies like that at the end of the book of the Prophet Daniel.
How are we to understand these prophecy fulfillment in the future if these nations are no longer there to participate in the fulfillment?
Isaiah 11- reference root of Jesse-
13The envy also of Ephraim shall depart,
And they that harass Judah shall be cut off;
Ephraim shall not envy Judah,
And Judah shall not vex Ephraim.
14And they shall fly down upon the shoulder of the Philistines on the west;
Together shall they spoil the children of the east;
They shall put forth their hand upon Edom and Moab;
And the children of Ammon shall obey them.

"In Isaiah , the prophecy about the root of Jesse": pointing us to it (chapter and verse numbers) would help others help you.

The new nations don't have to be biologically descended from the ancient nations. Rather, they can just exhibit similar cultural qualities.

Technically the nations still exist, we just don't know who is who anymore. See also Derech Hashem of Ramchal (pt. 1 ch. 4 iirc) for a detailed explanation.
